# Describe classes of quotient group

Tags: group-theory

I hope for your help in the next task:

$G=M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb Z)$ - integer matrices of order $2$.
Operation - addition.

$H$ - matrices of the form: 
$\left( {\matrix{
   a & b  \cr 
   2c & 2d  \cr 
 } } \right)$
 where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$

Obviously $H$ is a normal subgroup. I need to describe classes of quotient group $G/H$ and operation in it.

Also: which group is isomorphic to the group $G/H$?

I highly interested in describing classes of quotient group $G/H$. I have no idea how to complete this, because I've never made it with matrices.

I highly appreciate all answers. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use the notation $M_{n\times m}$ for matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's maybe a more intuitive way to approach this problem rather than appealing to the isomorphism theorem like Timbuc is leading you to do. Note that $G/H$ can be viewed as a set of equivalence classes. If $M,N\in G$, then $M\sim N$ if and only if $M-N\in H$, i.e. if $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22}\end{array}\right)$ and $N = \left(\begin{array}{cc} n_{11} & n_{12} \\ n_{21} & n_{22}\end{array}\right)$, then $M\sim N$ if and only if

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} m_{11}-n_{11} & m_{12} - n_{12} \\ m_{21} - n_{21} & m_{22}-n_{22}\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ 2c & 2d\end{array}\right)$$

for some $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$. That is, $m_{11} = n_{11}+a$, $m_{12} = n_{12}+b$, $m_{21} = n_{21}+2c$ and $m_{22} = n_{22}+2d$. Clearly since $m_{ij}$ and $n_{ij}$ are integers, it is always true that $m_{11} = n_{11}+a$ and $m_{12} = n_{12}+b$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. Thus the equivalence class is somewhat trivial with regards to the top row of elements.

The conditions $m_{21} = n_{21}+2c$ means that either both $m_{21}$ and $n_{21}$ are even or odd and likewise for $m_{22}$ and $n_{22}$. How many equivalence classes do we then have? Can you see how this answers your question?

Comment: I've looked on your and Timbuc's answers. And if I rightly understood we have 4 equivalence classes? 
$\left( {\matrix{ 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \cr } } \right)$
$\left( {\matrix{ 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 \cr } } \right)$
$\left( {\matrix{ 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 \cr } } \right)$
$\left( {\matrix{ 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 1\cr } } \right)$

Comment: Those are the representatives, yes. What group is that isomorphic to?

Comment: Is that isomorphic to group of integers modulo 4: $Z_4$ = {0, 1, 2, 3} ?

Comment: You would think so but what happens when you add an element to itself?

Comment: Yeah, if I add matrix to itself I'll get neutral matrix. I have to think about isomorhism.

Comment: I suppose G/H is isomorphic to group of matrices of the form:
$\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\pmod2$ ?

Comment: Well yes but there is a group you know which is isomorphic to it. What four element group has the property that every element is its own inverse?

Comment: Four element group where every element is its own inverse: 


{$\left( {\matrix{ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \cr 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \cr } } \right)$,
$\left( {\matrix{ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \cr 2 & 1 & 3 & 4 \cr } } \right)$,
$\left( {\matrix{ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \cr 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 \cr } } \right)$,
$\left( {\matrix{ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \cr 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \cr } } \right)$}

There is operation - multiplication. But in G/H - addition.

Comment: It's the Klein four group.

Comment: Is it not wrong that there is different operation in isomorphic groups?

Comment: Well they can be isomorphic without the operation being the same. For instance, $(\Bbb R,+)$ and $(\Bbb R^+,\cdot)$ are isomorphic but the operations are entirely different.

Comment: Thank you for help. But I have last question to make my mind clear, if it doesn't hard for you: I rightly understood that first row of equivalence classes always zero because classes depends only from second row elemets?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Define

$$\phi: G\to \Bbb Z_2^{2\times2}\;,\;\;\phi\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\c\pmod2&d\pmod2\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\pmod2$$

Check the above is a homomorphism (of abelian groups), and $\;H=\ker\phi\;$ .